# my canvas input slips away from the htmk title

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making a path finder html.

I am trying to make a head line above my canvas. But if I do the canvas is sliping into the headline and the input is wrong.

I've tried to put them in 2 separate divs but it doesn't work.
How do I solve this issue?

```
<div>
    <h1 style="color: white; background-color:purple;font-family: Comic Sans MS;">
        Welocome
    </h1>
</div>
<div><canvas id="gc"></canvas></div>
```

```js
     document.addEventListener("click", onClick);
    function click(squares){
    clicX = e.pageX;
    clicY = e.pageY;
    isChanged = false;
    squars.forEach(colum => {
        colum.forEach(squar => {
            x = squar[0];
            y = squar[1];
    if (clicX >= x+seperate && clicX <= x+seperate+width 
                && clicY >= y+seperate && clicY <= y+seperate+height) {
                    if (e.button == 2) {
                        squar[2] = isStart? "red":"blue"; //if there is start so it gone to red for end
                        isChanged = true;
                    }
                    else if (squar[2] != "grey") {
                        squar[2] = "grey";
                    }
                    else{
                        squar[2] = "black";
                    }
                    printSquares();
            }
        });
    });
    isChanged ? isStart = !isStart : false;
    isChanged = false;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is this all of your code?  clicking which element is supposed to trigger the javascript function?  try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

my solution was at the end that i was needed to make ajusments for every item i put in html doc. the ajusments in the code was in clickY. I calc the shift that the div makes and subtract the shift for the var.
ex:

```
pageShift = 65;
clicX = e.pageX;
clicY = e.pageY-pageShift;
```